# Eclipse DLTK: Adding wizards to the 'New' menu of ScriptExplorerPart

Tags: java, eclipse, dltk

I'm trying to add a wizard entry to a `ScriptExplorerPart` of the Dynamic Languages ToolKit for Eclipse.

The wizards are accessible from `File->New->Other...`, so at least I know they work. They are added using the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards`. What I would like is to have them added as indicated on [this screenshot](http://i52.tinypic.com/9amhiu.png).

To start with I figured it should probably be done using the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent`, as suggested [in this eclipse newslist](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg77871.html). This does not work however, as it seems like DLTK does not honor that extension point.

So, if anyone could point me in the right direction with regards to the correct extension point to use, or if there is another (better) way to add wizard shortcuts, I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

although this question is a bit old:
perspectives control the shortcuts in the menus. you can use the extension point org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions to add your wizard to new.
it should look something like this:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension targetID="yourPerspective">
    ....
     <newWizardShortcut
           id="idOfYourNewWizard">
     </newWizardShortcut>
  </perspectiveExtension>
</extension>
```

your wizard will then show up under `File > New`. 
for more information, consult those two links:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_perspectiveExtension.htm 
and 
 http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't work on the project for which I needed to do this anymore, but I will point the current maintainer in the direction of this post, if he hasn't figured it out for himself by now.

Comment: i also need it for myself in a bit for my project, but i hope it helped anyways :)

Comment: a note: if it won't show up using above, reset the perspective (Window > Reset Perspective). i just had the issue that my wizard wouldn't show up although I did everything correct, and resetting the perspective did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer but it no longer works in the new eclipse plugin. Just want to provide a working solution for the current version:

go to plugin.xml –> Extensions –> org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent (create if not existing) –> New –> commonWizard

and then

type: new for the New submenu and import for Import submenu

wizardId: the id of your wizard for new/import