# Eclipse plugin: Add my project type to the "new" menu

Tags: menu, eclipse-plugin, project

I am writing an Eclipse plugin, and I have a wizard that create my project.

When pressing menu -> New there are two options: Java Project and Project,only when I click on Project  can choose my plugin project type.

Is it possible to make the new menu to contain my project type as well? like menu -> New will have three options: Java Project , XXX Project and Project?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421447/eclipse-dltk-adding-wizards-to-the-new-menu-of-scriptexplorerpart which is about a file but the solution should be identical for your new project wizard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Eclipse DLTK: Adding wizards to the 'New' menu of ScriptExplorerPart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421447/eclipse-dltk-adding-wizards-to-the-new-menu-of-scriptexplorerpart) which is about a file but the solution should be identical for your new project wizard.